# Why doesn't the renderer correctly render a model built with Three.CanvasTexture after tf.toPixel(image, canvas)

Tags: three.js

I want to use `THREE.CanvasTexture` to generate a texture by canvas.Now,I use tensorflowjs to predict an image,then use `tf.toPixels(y,document.getElementById("tensorflow"))` to output the predicted image on canvas.

Firstly,I define some basic variables，like
`

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('tensorflow');

var  canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
var model=null;
const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/tensorflowjs_model.pb';
const WEIGHTS_URL = 'web_model/weights_manifest.json';
const OUTPUT_NODE_NAME = 'generator/Tanh1';
const INPUT_NODE_NAME='concat';
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material =  new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    vertexShader: document.querySelector( '#bleed-vert' ).textContent.trim(),
    fragmentShader: document.querySelector( '#bleed-frag' ).textContent.trim(),
    uniforms: {
        buffer:  { value: canvasTexture }

    }
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );`
```

Secondly,I loadModel and predict it,and output the final result by `tf.toPixels(y,document.getElementById("tensorflow"));`

But the render result is always black. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you can make a codepen to demonstrate the problem, it will be easier to look at the issue

Comment: Is github OK?？？

Comment: Yeah, it will be fine as long as you tell how to reproduce the error in the readme.

Comment: https://github.com/yiifanLu/canvasTexture ，you can directly run the demo

Comment: What problem....

Comment: I initially thought that it was a tensoflow issue. But that's not. I removed the `tensorflow.js` tag so that the issue can be addressed under `three.js` tag

Comment: I tried this process: read 0000.png by  canvas directly, then create Canvastexture, the mesh will render correctly